# How can i improve this?

Tags: python

I am currently self teaching myself Python , and this is my first program. I am doing some simple projects so i can improve. Would like to hear feedback on this one.

```
import random

print("There is a number between 1 and 100 guess it and you will win a price : ")


def guess():
    # A simple guess game.
    random_number = random.randint(1, 5)
    flag = True
    user_guess = []

    while flag:

        user_number = input("Enter the number : ")

        user_guess.append(user_number)

        if int(user_number) < random_number:
            print("You have to go higher")

        elif int(user_number) > random_number:
            print("You have to go lower ")

        else:
            flag = False
            print("Congrats you win !!! \nThe numbers of guesses before you won : ")
            print(len(user_guess))


guess()

while True:
    play_again = input("Do you like to play again ? : (y/n): ")
    if play_again == 'y':
        guess()
    else:
        print("Thank you for playing have a nice day!!! ")
        break
```

Comment: With some work, this might be right for Code Review, but you need to be clearer on your aim

Comment: Isn't the number supposed to be between 1 and 100? `random_number = random.randint(1, 5)`

Comment: @SilverSlash It is easier to test that way that is why it is `random_number = random.randint(1, 5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your program will throw an exception if the user enters an invalid (nondigit) character. Use [isdigit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) to avoid such cases.
2. Converting `user_number` to integer every time you want to compare it with some other integer is costly, and frivolous. Convert it once and reassign it to `user_number`.
3. `flag` is not necessary. Use `while True`, and break when needed.
4. Keeping an entire `list` object just to count user input is a bit overkill. Have a single integer (`count` in my example) and use it.
5. You print *"between 1 and 100"* but your program creates a random integer between 1 and 5. I am not sure about your intentions with doing that (perhaps a debugging aid), but I presume it's a small mistake.
6. A minor suggestion, move the `print("There is a number between 1 and 100 guess it and you will win a price : ")` to the `guess` function since it makes more sense for the function to declare its own purpose.

Here's how I would make those changes to the `guess` function:

```
def guess():
    print("There is a number between 1 and 100 guess it and you will win a price : ")
    # A simple guess game.
    random_number = random.randint(1, 100)
    # flag = True obsolete
    count = 0
    while True:
        user_number = input("Enter the number : ")
        if (user_number.isdigit()):
          user_number = int(user_number)
        else:
          print("Invalid:")
          continue
        count += 1
        if user_number < random_number:
            print("You have to go higher")
        elif user_number > random_number:
            print("You have to go lower ")
        else:
            print("Congrats you win !!! \nThe numbers of guesses before you won : ")
            print(count)
            break
```

Comment: Thank you and `random_number = random.randint(1, 5)` was for testing only .